# Set moving object's area

Tags: python, opencv

I've worked with several methods in OpenCV to identify moving objects and track them based on changing pixels or color, but nothing regarding the area where these objects are moving, so I'm coming here to ask if anyone has a clue about this topic.

Conceptually the idea is pretty simple: let's say we have a bunch of moving objects in a video

[image: Initial set of objects]

As these objects pass by we would like to identify the boundaries of these objects or "trails":

[image: Moving objects]

By the end of the video, or after a time set, the idea would be to know what these boundaries are so we can compute them (area for instance):

[image: Area used]

My hunch would be to use [Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html#lucas-kanade) to track the corner points as the objects pass by and keep the ones further away, but so far nothing has worked and therefore I'm unsure this is the proper approach.

Would anyone have a clue about the approach to take? Thanks!

Comment: Are these object you're tracking in videos, or are you really watching shapes moving like in the images?  Do you get bounding boxes of the detected objects?  Is anything else moving in the scene?

Comment: Yeah, these circles above represent moving objects I'm tracking in a video (the only moving things in the scene) with a flat background and with their contours identified and drawn, so I'm not printing bounding boxes but could if I had to.

Comment: convex hull would give you the area for a single image. If you know the movement for each of thr circles you can interpolate positiond between two frames.